# Calling overloaded function from another overloaded function

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a couple of helper functions for the Notion API that parse properties with a specific type. I have two functions I'm trying to implement: `optionalValue` and `requiredValue`.

For `optionalValue`, I'm using function overloads, which works really well. Here's a simplified example.

```js
type Value = { text: string | undefined };

export function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "number"): number | undefined;
export function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "date"): Date | undefined;
export function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "string"): string | undefined;

export function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "number" | "date" | "string") {
  if (type === "number") {
    const number = Number(value.text);
    return isNaN(number) ? undefined : number;
  }

  if (type === "date") {
    const date = value.text ? new Date(value.text) : undefined;
    return date && !isNaN(date.getTime()) ? date : undefined;
  }

  return value.text;
}
```

This seems to work well and doesn't result in any compiler errors.

However, I'd like for my `requiredValue` function to have the exact same signature, and I can't seem to find a way to make it work. Here's what I'd like to do:

```js
export const requiredValue: typeof optionalValue = (value, type) => {
  const parsedValue = optionalValue(value, type);

  if (parsedValue === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`The ${type} value '${value}' could not be parsed.`);
  }

  return parsedValue;
};
```

This produces a compiler error:

```
typescript: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(value: Value, type: "number"): number | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"string" | "number" | "date"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"number"'.
      Type '"string"' is not assignable to type '"number"'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(value: Value, type: "date"): Date | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"string" | "number" | "date"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"date"'.
      Type '"string"' is not assignable to type '"date"'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(value: Value, type: "string"): string | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"string" | "number" | "date"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"string"'.
      Type '"number"' is not assignable to type '"string"'. [2769]
```

I've tried different variations of `requiredValue`, but I can't find anything that makes the compiler happy. Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: Can you explain what `PageObjectResponse`?

Comment: ① Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Undeclared types like `PageObjectResponse` should be defined or replaced with native types.  ② Presumably you're running into [ms/TS#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) and the workaround is either to add manual catchall call signatures or assert your way out of it.  If I see a [mre] here I'll provide a concrete example.  If that turns out to be the issue I could write an answer or find a suitable dupe target.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I've updated my question with a simplified example to remove any confusion.

Comment: @jcalz It's hard to tell for sure from that issue, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: TypeScript only knows how to deal with overloads when you call exactly one of their call signatures. They don't generalize/compose well.  One issue stopping you is ms/TS#14107 and another is [ms/TS#47669](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669). If you want to just prevent errors and make the compiler "happy" you can use type assertions and/or `any` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wXgg1W).  If you need the compiler to actually *verify* what you did is accurate/safe then it is harder/impossible. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll answer/dupe; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in TypeScript have a lot of caveats.  They are only really type checked properly when you're calling them, and only when you are calling them with exactly one of their call signatures.  Generally speaking, if you run into trouble with overloads, you will either want to refactor so as to avoid them, or use something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to push through them and move on.  There is unfortunately no option to use overloads and have anything close to accurate and complete compiler-verified type safety.

---

Because you wrote `optionalValue()` with a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#description), the body is checked *loosely* against the call signatures.  If you were to, say, switch the conditions on the `if (type === "number")` and `if (type === "date")` checks, the compiler wouldn't notice.  This drawback is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235) and cannot really be fixed, because doing it "correctly" would require the compiler to type check the function once per call signature, and that would scale very badly.  This isn't a problem you're asking about, presumably because it's a false negative sort of problem that results in the lack of error messages where you might expect them.  All you can do here is be careful.

---

Inside `requiredValue()`, the type of `type` is inferred to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those of the `type` parameters from the call signatures in `typeof optionalValue`, namely `"number" | "date" | "string"`. But none of your three call signatures to `optionalValue()` accept a `"number" | "date" | "string"` as the second argument.  No, the implementation signature does not count (it is not visible from outside the function, as per [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)).  So the call results in a "no overload matches this call" error.  You might think that the compiler could automatically accept a mixture of the call signatures, but this is not currently supported.  There's a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).

If you want to call an overloaded function with a union of its call signatures, you must either add a new catch-all call signature yourself like

```
// original call signatures
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "number"): number | undefined;
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "date"): Date | undefined;
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "string"): string | undefined;

// added call signature
function optionalValue(
  value: Value, type: "number" | "date" | "string"
): number | Date | string | undefined;

// implementation
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "number" | "date" | "string") {
  /* ✂ snip ✂ */
}
```

or you need to use a type assertion to convince the compiler that you are calling some particular existing call signature

```
const parsedValue = optionalValue(value, type as number); // ‍♂️
```

Neither is great.  The manual call signature is probably more correct, but it doesn't scale well.

---

Once you fix that you'll notice that you still get an error:

```
const requiredValue: typeof optionalValue = (value, type) => { // error!
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
/* Type '(value: Value, type: "string" | "number" | "date") => string | number | Date' 
 is not assignable to type '{ 
 (value: Value, type: "number"): number | undefined; 
 (value: Value, type: "date"): Date | undefined; 
 (value: Value, type: "string"): string | undefined; 
 (value: Value, type: "string" | ... | "date"): string | ... | undefined; }'.
 Type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322) */

  const parsedValue = optionalValue(value, type);

  if (parsedValue === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`The ${type} value '${value}' could not be parsed.`);
  }

  return parsedValue 
};
```

That's because you're trying to implement `requiredValue()` as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), a function expression.  And while TypeScript checks overloaded function *declarations* too loosely, it checks overloaded function expressions *too strictly*.  It still can't follow the logic accurately by checking the implementation once per call signature.  So it makes a simplification, like before.  But unlike before where the simplification is (more or less) to check that the return types match *some* call signature (even if it's not the right one), now the simplification is to check that the return types match *every* call signature.  This is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669), which essentially asks for function expressions to be checked like function declarations.  For now it's not part of the language, though.

So to make the compiler happy you'd have to return a value of type `(string | undefined) & (number | undefined) & (Date | undefined)` which is just `undefined`.  If you write `return undefined` the compiler will be happy.  But that's not what you want to do.  Instead, again, you'll need a type assertion like `return parsedValue as any`, using [the intentionally loose `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to avoid the error.

---

So now we have something like

```
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "number"): number | undefined;
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "date"): Date | undefined;
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "string"): string | undefined;
function optionalValue(
  value: Value, type: "number" | "date" | "string"
): number | Date | string | undefined;
function optionalValue(value: Value, type: "number" | "date" | "string") {
  /* ✂ snip ✂ */
}

const requiredValue: typeof optionalValue = (value, type) => {
  const parsedValue = optionalValue(value, type); // okay
  if (parsedValue === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`The ${type} value '${value}' could not be parsed.`);
  }
  return parsedValue as any; // okay
};
```

And the compiler is "happy".  But the happiness comes from a bunch of workarounds that loosen type safety.  `optionalValue`'s body isn't guaranteed to be type safe, and neither is `requiredValue` because of the `as any` at the end.   This doesn't necessarily mean that you should abandon overloads; they are very useful for their intended purpose.  But if you're going to use them, you should at least be aware of the various issues surrounding them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQN5WBAHsALigGdgAnASwDsBzKAHyiSoBMIAzaiFqAXwG4AUIID0IqAGNECEhRpU4wJGQjFBeMAHsywKO2YTgFTVSiawRk4njIIACgBuiFERsoANNnAQiAIipIALYARhBkvgCURAEhYQxMrBxcLEIa2rr6VIbGpuaWCghu9k62rs4QnqCQfiyKEJFEACJ18cxsnFTcqbhaOnoG+WYWOdbljuVltpXefqSUtA0k5NR0jG1JnSmi4p0A7pLSsvKKyhDqPen9WYN5I4VjJS6w5dPVUP5BoeHxvrU4vj85itFjEvvFmjh4kDaK1Eh0usIxFAKIEwAgIIEIFRgIocudehkBjkhvlRrZxqVnlMvG8PrFvoxfnUAYzoTRIphhFBkewoHYqmhUOg6V8ORhBNzuRITKQoKC4ugAHKfMIUlAAOhw+AiQklUBUSjIpgoxEVcEVdnlZAiUAA-Al2skoNEVWRdXwuTy+QKoELhX96jbxXrpVRZQHfVBHhBNXhdPa9lAIcVyrHtc6HRsEXqDcpTBGAGQFqAAQhNZotAfVNAgwAAKij7BEbfaI0R1vCttzeJ7c0ao6mtcAhD38ZdQ7KVABHJAUFQsIpEAWaXm3Kz3WyRtUVGkQG2oAB8nKlMt0YDgZGI3CKkbXBSK29ee-dSM0AGs4CAoLsKMAABZQHALBsDwUgIDIxByAohrQNQJJ3EUnoULydjnpe17lL6QqZp2QYSpK-5kJo+yJgAomQRFkHYAAGdZ-tAAAkGACrwA6bgA5Ex0a8OxkiaEgCA8FQmi6KEUBoVeLDqtROr4T23J9qYEkYZucDEIBVAgPwUCvh+ICCAIogAFRQHW3hQOx26TB4u6zMsCw-FaLLvAGHKHks8yrHKrrgnUvH4ci6nCboamQccwTotgmi7hZWABVZVI2QKfhOVE3n0rCjqbNp8XRtZO7JS5zJpcmmVZikUC5RMiUFTM7xsosbJlZ2OWSglRRPnZnnOeqvVQAAjFAgTaNAvXqj8rlpU1jBjVAABMQ0jVAs1rHCyTaTx6r4WZkAWdN6Vgowya8SacoiYBxBhQoEXQMA0U+uxVrNck7FbXqO3QOxbInUF52hVBcA3VFMWPa6r12HNADMc1zTaRkiEAA)

Comment: Thank you for this awesome and detailed explanation!